# Zune + Ubuntu, What are my options?

Tags: rhythmbox, sound

I have a Zune HD (don't ask).

Is there any alternative to using this in Ubuntu besides creating a virtual Windows environment (in say Virtual Box or VMWare) and running the Zune software there?

Comment: If it makes you feel any better. iPods aren't all that great in Linux either.

Comment: Voted you up for making me feel better :)

Comment: I was under the impression that the Zune HD was supposed to be a (relatively, at least) good device?

Comment: It is a decent device - it is just not a very "open" device and therefore you are locked into using the Zune software on Windows to move media onto it.

Comment: @Alaukik: personally, I tend to expect rrational argument, as opposed to flame-bait and brand-bias... =/

Comment: @David microsoft is not a GNU/Linux friendly company it is a competitor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I understand, no one has been able to crack the ZMTP protocol. So unfortunately you have no other options.

My poor friend is facing the same problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

Zune doesn't work with Wine (the Windows-Linux compatibility layer) and Windows Phone devices don't feature USB storage mode so **your only option regarding Zune really is running it in Virtual Box** + Windows.
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+zune+virtualbox

### Detailed information:

[How to sync my music and photos with Windows Phone 7 device?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73866/how-to-sync-my-music-and-photos-with-windows-phone-7-device)