# How to sync my music and photos with Windows Phone 7 device?

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, phone, windows-phone

Is there is anything like a Zune or Windows Phone connector for ubuntu? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your options:

**Zune installed on virtual machine (e.g. VirtualBox)**
Zune doesn't work with Wine (the Windows-Linux compatibility layer) and Windows Phone devices don't feature USB storage mode so your only option regarding Zune really is running it in Virtual Box + Windows.
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+zune+virtualbox

**USB mass storage hack on virtual machine**
You install Windows with Zune on a virtual machine and use a small registry hack as per instructions given here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=975401

**Cloud storage** (e.g. MediaFire.com or SkyDrive.com) **as a middle-man** (i.e. [your computer] <-> [cloud storage] <-> [your Windows Phone smartphone]) **doesn't work**. WP does not allow downloading MP3 to phone except from specialized websites/apps of specialized music stores/providers like 7digital.

Related:
[Zune + Ubuntu, What are my options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307/zune-ubuntu-what-are-my-options)