# Thinking of switching to Ubuntu, can it do all the following things?

Tags: microsoft

Sorry for the basic question, but can Ubuntu:

Access Microsoft SkyDrive, on which some important documents are stored;

Access Microsoft Zune, which is how I get music onto my Windows Phone, or can it provide a service that's more or less as easy to use;

Play specific games I've downloaded from GoG.com?

Hopefully the answer is "yes!" to all the above!

Thanks all!

Comment: Regarding playing games from gog.com, take a look at coteyr's answer to the question [How do you play games on an Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210985/how-do-you-play-games-on-a-ubuntu-desktop-i-noticed-the-laptops-only-have-intel/210989#210989). I'll correct his typo for you, instead of "play on linux" it should be "PlayOnLinux".

Comment: Thanks, Karel! Wow, Wine looks massively complicated... I guess I was hoping to be able to run the program more or less as simply as I do it from Windows, just by clicking! It looks from Wine as if I need to download that third-party app, then download an installer, mess around with the code, and then hope for the best! I must sound very squeamish, but that is a little off-putting!

Comment: It's really not that difficult. Using PlayOnLinux you can create a different set of software packages for running each game in Wine, so that the packages you use for installing one game won't interfere with the packages you use for another game. Also you can check the games for compatibility before you install them at the [WineHQ App Database](http://appdb.winehq.org/).

Comment: About wine: To install it under Ubuntu, simply search for it in software center and hit the install button. No need to do anything with code. After installing WINE, many programs can be installed and run simply by double clicking on the .exe, but using PlayOnLinux makes it much easier to handle installations (sometimes they don't work without additional effort, which is taken care of by PlayOnLinux) and to keep different programs in separate WINEPREFIXes (in general a good idea...).

Comment: @karel You may want to make this an answer but explain what it means to create different set ups with PlayOnLinux.  It's not difficult only if you have never done it before. ;-)

Comment: @maggotbrain OK, I did it, but I also asked soulsource if he wants to take over my thread.

Answer (score 1):

As for SkyDrive, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23230/how-do-i-mount-a-windows-live-skydrive-account-as-a-partition)

As for Zune, this doesn't sound currently possible, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307/zune-ubuntu-what-are-my-options) post, although this is two years old and therefore possibly outdated.

As for games, karel's comment says it all :-).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It looks like I would have to piece together solutions from all over the internet to get these things to run, which I suppose is kind of the point for an open-source project like Ubuntu. It's a bit more intimidating than I thought it would be!

Comment: Well.. not the intention. It's mostly because microsoft doesn't "open" their platforms for use with different systems. They kinda want you to lock in to using Windows - their own product after all.  As for games, building any application for different operating systems can be quite a LOT of work - sometimes even entirely impossible - which means many companies do not make the effort since the linux market is too small ;-).

Answer (score 0):

For Sky Drive , You have answered , I think (It's Better &) you can Download them & Put them on Ubuntu one that also works with Windows! ( I used Sky Drive before & I think Ubuntu one is very faster too !)
**I know anyone can say its not an answer !**